# How to pass a context from a wizard to controller and get the value of that context in controller in Odoo 12?

Tags: python, python-requests, odoo, odoo-12

I have a wizard and I select a department, then I call an action (defined in xml) which calls a controller. I have also set (defined) my custom context and passed the selected department id in the context. I want to pass this context upon calling the action which loads a controller to the controller. In the controller, I need to access the passed context's values. This is the code where I set context in the controller and return an action with context:

```
@api.multi
def action_select_department(self):
    ctx = dict(self._context)
    if self.department_id:
        self.state = 'display'
        ctx.update({'dep_id': self.department_id.id})
        print('Dept id:::::::::::::::::::', self.department_id.id, ctx)
        return {
            'name': _('Website Next Patient Screen'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'context': ctx,
            'url': '/next_patient',
            'target': 'self'
        }
```

And this is the controller code where I want to get the context:

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.tools.translate import _


class hms_next_patient_screen(http.Controller):
    @http.route(['/next_patient'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def next_patient(self, **kw):
        ctx = request.env.context.copy()
        dept = http.request.evn['nl_hms_next_patient.next.patiend.screen.wizard']
        print('DEPT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::', dept)
        print (">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", ctx, self, kw)
        app_obj = request.env['hms.appointment']
        one = app_obj.sudo().search([('state', '=', 'in_consultation')], limit=1)
        next = app_obj.sudo().search([('state', '=', 'waiting')])
        two = three = four = app_obj
        if len(next)>=1:
            two = next[0]
        if len(next)>=2:
            three = next[1]
        if len(next)>=3:
            four = next[2]
        return request.render("acs_hms_next_patient_screen.next_patient_view",{'one':one,'two':two,'three':three,'four':four})
```

The method in wizard works fine and the action is called with loading the controller. But, I can't access the context value in the controller. How can I pass the custom context and access it in the controller?

Comment: Have you thought about using a URL parameter for the department_id?

Comment: Actually no, I just wanted to pass a context with department_id and I didn't think about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass the details as context to a controller.You can pass it with the the url.
Please try this.

In the wizard,

```
 return {
      'name': _('Website Next Patient Screen'),
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
      'url': '/next_patient?dep_id=%s' % self.department_id.id
      'target': 'self'
   }
```

You can get the details that passed in the url, from the `kw` argument in controller.

In Controller,

```
  department_id = kw.get('dep_id')
```